# How to plot a variable according to its row order

Tags: r

So I'm doing a econometrics project and I decided to do it on R, bare in mind that I'm fairly new on this. I got a dataframe of macroeconomic data like GDP, unemployment rate, interest rate, etc. I don't think the subject is relevant, but I figured it would be easier for you guys to understand what I'm trying to do.

Now, all of the data is grouped in quarters (groups of three months), and each of these is ordered from top to bottom in chronological order.

First six rows of my data with its respective labels:
[image: First six rows of my data with its respective labels]

*periodo* would be the quarter the data refers to (it starts with the third one because there was missing data). So T3 would be the third quarter of 2000, T4 the fourth one, T5 the first one of 2001 and so on. It may not be the most comprehensible way of showing the time passage, but it is understandable nonetheless. (Except that maybe R is not able to understand it? I seem to be unable to plot any variable against *periodo*)

So all of the data is indeed ordered chronologically, what I want to do is to plot any of these variables, take *desempleo* for example, against time, to see how it goes up and down and whatever the graph would show. But, for my purposes, the time variable isn't really important. it could be quarters or years, numbers from 1 to 74, whatever. What is really relevant is the order in which *desempleo* is already ordered, like the number of the row it is in. My question is if there is any way to use **ggplot2** to achieve this, without having to add any new columns or having to manipulate my data too much.

I tried the following code:

```
ggplot(original, aes(x = order, y = desempleo)) + 
  geom_path(lineend = "butt", linejoin = "round", linemitre = 1)
```

It obviously doesn't work since the variable *order* doesn't exist, but I hope this gives you an idea of what I am trying to do. If you could give me an answer somewhat similar to the code I'm trying to do it with, it would be really helpful, but any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you please `dput()` your data and add to the question in order to help you!

Comment: is adding a column completely out of question? It would be really easy to just add this variable `order` you use in the syntax by writing: `original$order = 1:length(original$periodo)`. It would create a variable ranging from 1 to the number of lines in your dataset and you could use it to plot anything.